# How to check if emacs shell buffer busy or not?

Tags: shell

If I start a long-running process in an emacs shell create by `(shell)`, the shell will be busy for a while.  How can I detect that programmatically (i.e., using elisp)?

I tried: get the process by `(get-process "shell")` and test `(process-live-p proc)`, but it always return `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun shell-process-running-child-p (process-name)
  (interactive)
  (if (process-running-child-p process-name)
      (print t)
    (print nil)))
```